# memory behavior on Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03

Tags: memory-leaks, out-of-memory

We observe an increasing memory usage of our ec2 instances over time.
After two weeks we have to reboot our systems.

On this machines run some docker containers. Let's have a look
with 'free -m' after 14 days(I stopped the docker daemon now):

```
$free -m
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7977       7852        124          0          4        573
-/+ buffers/cache:       7273        703
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Now I run 'ps_mem':

```
Private  +   Shared  =  RAM used        Program

124.0 KiB +  64.5 KiB = 188.5 KiB       agetty
140.0 KiB +  60.5 KiB = 200.5 KiB       acpid
180.0 KiB +  41.5 KiB = 221.5 KiB       rngd
200.0 KiB + 205.5 KiB = 405.5 KiB       lvmpolld
320.0 KiB +  89.5 KiB = 409.5 KiB       irqbalance
320.0 KiB + 232.5 KiB = 552.5 KiB       lvmetad
476.0 KiB +  99.5 KiB = 575.5 KiB       auditd
624.0 KiB + 105.5 KiB = 729.5 KiB       init
756.0 KiB +  72.5 KiB = 828.5 KiB       crond
292.0 KiB + 622.5 KiB = 914.5 KiB       udevd (3)
560.0 KiB + 377.0 KiB = 937.0 KiB       mingetty (6)
1.0 MiB + 194.5 KiB =   1.2 MiB       ntpd
1.1 MiB + 256.0 KiB =   1.4 MiB       dhclient (2)
2.5 MiB + 103.5 KiB =   2.6 MiB       rsyslogd
3.1 MiB + 259.0 KiB =   3.4 MiB       sendmail.sendmail (2)
3.0 MiB + 609.0 KiB =   3.6 MiB       sudo (2)
3.6 MiB +   1.6 MiB =   5.2 MiB       bash (5)
2.9 MiB +   4.3 MiB =   7.2 MiB       sshd (9)
14.5 MiB + 413.5 KiB =  14.9 MiB       dmeventd
---------------------------------
                     45.4 MiB
=================================
```

Now I try to allocate new memory with the 'stress' tool(http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/):

```
$ stress --vm 1 --vm-bytes 1G --timeout 10s --verbose
stress: info: [11120] dispatching hogs: 0 cpu, 0 io, 1 vm, 0 hdd
stress: dbug: [11120] using backoff sleep of 3000us
stress: dbug: [11120] setting timeout to 10s
stress: dbug: [11120] --> hogvm worker 1 [11121] forked
stress: dbug: [11121] allocating 1073741824 bytes ...
stress: FAIL: [11121] (494) hogvm malloc failed: Cannot allocate memory
stress: FAIL: [11120] (394) <-- worker 11121 returned error 1
stress: WARN: [11120] (396) now reaping child worker processes
stress: FAIL: [11120] (451) failed run completed in 0s
```

==> 'stress' is not able to allocate 1G of new memory.

But I do not understand where all my memory is gone?!

Here comes the output of 'top' (similiar to ps_mem):

```
Tasks: 107 total,   1 running,  66 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,     0.0%st
Mem:   8168828k total,  8045784k used,   123044k free,     5656k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   589372k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
2030 root      20   0  102m  17m 5812 S  0.0  0.2   1:21.36 dmeventd
11145 root      20   0 82664 6604 5752 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd
11130 root      20   0  183m 4472 3824 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sudo
18339 ec2-user  20   0  114m 3896 1744 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.08 bash
2419 root      20   0  241m 3552 1188 S  0.0  0.0   2:07.85 rsyslogd
11146 sshd      20   0 80588 3440 2612 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
11131 root      20   0  112m 3288 2924 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bash
17134 root      20   0  117m 3084 2008 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
17148 ec2-user  20   0  112m 2992 2620 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 bash
 2605 root      20   0 85496 2776 1064 S  0.0  0.0   0:21.44 sendmail
 2614 smmsp     20   0 81088 2704 1208 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.17 sendmail
15228 root      20   0  112m 2632 2228 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 bash
    1 root      20   0 19684 2376 2068 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.91 init
 2626 root      20   0  118m 2276 1644 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.45 crond
 2233 root      20   0  9412 2244 1748 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.49 dhclient
11147 root      20   0 15364 2176 1856 R  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 top
 2584 ntp       20   0  113m 2128 1308 S  0.0  0.0   0:49.60 ntpd
```

Where are these damned 7273MB memory consumed?

cat /proc/meminfo

```
MemTotal:        8168828 kB
MemFree:          129736 kB
MemAvailable:     567464 kB
Buffers:            5116 kB
Cached:           585504 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           476920 kB
Inactive:         130228 kB
Active(anon):      22340 kB
Inactive(anon):       80 kB
Active(file):     454580 kB
Inactive(file):   130148 kB
Unevictable:       17620 kB
Mlocked:           17620 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                16 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         34088 kB
Mapped:            14668 kB
Shmem:                80 kB
Slab:            5625876 kB
SReclaimable:     142240 kB
SUnreclaim:      5483636 kB
KernelStack:        2016 kB
PageTables:         4384 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     4084412 kB
Committed_AS:     109856 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     7286784 kB
DirectMap2M:     1101824 kB
```

Output of slabtop

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 8445426 / 11391340 (74.1%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 533926 / 533926 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 78 / 101 (77.2%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 5033325.10K / 5414048.91K (93.0%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.47K / 9.44K

 OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
 3216990 525372  16%    0.09K  76595      42    306380K kmalloc-96
 3101208 3101011  99%    1.00K 219166      32   7013312K kmalloc-1024
 2066976 2066841  99%    0.32K  86124      24    688992K taskstats
 1040384 1039935  99%    0.03K   8128     128     32512K kmalloc-32
 1038080 1037209  99%    0.06K  16220      64     64880K kmalloc-64
 516719 516719 100%    2.09K 113785  15   3641120K request_queue
 223356  22610  10%    0.57K   7977  28    127632K radix_tree_node
 52740  39903  75%    0.13K   1758   30  7032K kernfs_node_cache
```

Now I rebooted the machine and did a 'perf kmem record --caller'. After some seconds I had to cancel because the file data.perf was already over 1GB lager. I did a 'perf kmem stat --caller' and here comes the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Callsite                           | Total_alloc/Per | Total_req/Per   | Hit      | Ping-pong | Frag
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 dm_open+2b                         |       240/8     |       120/4     |       30 |         0 | 50,000%
 match_number+2a                    |       120/8     |        60/4     |       15 |         0 | 50,000%
 rebuild_sched_domains_locked+dd    |        72/8     |        36/4     |        9 |         0 | 50,000%
 dm_btree_del+2b                    |     40960/4096  |     20720/2072  |       10 |         0 | 49,414%
 sk_prot_alloc+7c                   |     86016/2048  |     44016/1048  |       42 |         0 | 48,828%
 hugetlb_cgroup_css_alloc+29        |      2560/512   |      1320/264   |        5 |         0 | 48,438%
 blk_throtl_init+2a                 |     15360/1024  |      8040/536   |       15 |         0 | 47,656%
 bpf_int_jit_compile+6e             |     40960/8192  |     21440/4288  |        5 |         0 | 47,656%
 mem_cgroup_css_alloc+2f            |     10240/2048  |      5360/1072  |        5 |         2 | 47,656%
 alloc_disk_node+32                 |     30720/2048  |     16560/1104  |       15 |         0 | 46,094%
 mem_cgroup_css_alloc+166           |      5120/1024  |      2800/560   |        5 |         2 | 45,312%
 blkcg_css_alloc+3b                 |      2560/512   |      1400/280   |        5 |         0 | 45,312%
 kobject_uevent_env+be              |   1224704/4096  |    698464/2336  |      299 |         0 | 42,969%
 uevent_show+81                     |    675840/4096  |    385440/2336  |      165 |         0 | 42,969%
 blkg_alloc+3c                      |     40960/1024  |     23680/592   |       40 |         0 | 42,188%
 dm_table_create+34                 |      7680/512   |      4560/304   |       15 |         0 | 40,625%
 journal_init_common+34             |     30720/2048  |     18360/1224  |       15 |         0 | 40,234%
 throtl_pd_alloc+2b                 |     56320/1024  |     34320/624   |       55 |         0 | 39,062%
 strndup_user+3f                    |     14496/17    |      8917/10    |      829 |         0 | 38,486%
 alloc_trial_cpuset+19              |     14336/1024  |      8848/632   |       14 |         0 | 38,281%
 cpuset_css_alloc+29                |      5120/1024  |      3160/632   |        5 |         0 | 38,281%
 proc_reg_open+33                   |     48768/64    |     30480/40    |      762 |         0 | 37,500%
 get_mountpoint+73                  |     26432/64    |     16520/40    |      413 |         0 | 37,500%
 alloc_pipe_info+aa                 |    219136/1024  |    136960/640   |      214 |        12 | 37,500%
 alloc_fair_sched_group+f0          |     38400/512   |     24000/320   |       75 |         0 | 37,500%
 __alloc_workqueue_key+77           |     15360/512   |      9600/320   |       30 |         0 | 37,500%
 newary+69                          |     15360/512   |      9600/320   |       30 |         0 | 37,500%
 disk_expand_part_tbl+74            |       960/64    |       600/40    |       15 |         0 | 37,500%
 alloc_dax+29                       |       120/8     |        75/5     |       15 |         0 | 37,500%
 kernfs_mount_ns+3c                 |       320/64    |       200/40    |        5 |         0 | 37,500%
 bucket_table_alloc+be              |     16640/978   |     10496/617   |       17 |        12 | 36,923%
 __alloc_workqueue_key+250          |      7680/512   |      4920/328   |       15 |         0 | 35,938%
 journal_init_common+1b9            |     61440/4096  |     40920/2728  |       15 |         0 | 33,398%
 kernfs_fop_write+b3                |      2248/11    |      1507/7     |      191 |         0 | 32,963%
 __alloc_skb+72                     |   3698176/876   |   2578048/611   |     4217 |       115 | 30,289%
 alloc_pid+33                       |     80896/128   |     56944/90    |      632 |        43 | 29,608%
 alloc_pipe_info+3d                 |     41088/192   |     29104/136   |      214 |        12 | 29,167%
 device_create_groups_vargs+59      |     15360/1024  |     10920/728   |       15 |         0 | 28,906%
 sget_userns+ee                     |    112640/2048  |     80960/1472  |       55 |         8 | 28,125%
 key_alloc+13e                      |       480/96    |       350/70    |        5 |         0 | 27,083%
 load_elf_phdrs+49                  |    153600/602   |    113176/443   |      255 |         0 | 26,318%
 alloc_vfsmnt+aa                    |     11752/22    |      8765/17    |      513 |       130 | 25,417%
 __memcg_init_list_lru_node+6b      |     35200/32    |     26400/24    |     1100 |       160 | 25,000%
 proc_self_get_link+96              |     12352/16    |      9264/12    |      772 |         0 | 25,000%
 memcg_kmem_get_cache+9e            |     46336/64    |     34752/48    |      724 |         0 | 25,000%
 kernfs_fop_open+286                |     45056/64    |     33792/48    |      704 |         0 | 25,000%
 insert_shadow+27                   |     16544/32    |     12408/24    |      517 |         3 | 25,000%
 allocate_cgrp_cset_links+70        |     28800/64    |     21600/48    |      450 |         0 | 25,000%

ext4_ext_remove_space+8db          |     12352/64    |      9264/48    |      193 |         0 | 25,000%
 dev_exception_add+25               |      5760/64    |      4320/48    |       90 |         0 | 25,000%
 mempool_create_node+4e             |      8160/96    |      6120/72    |       85 |         0 | 25,000%
 alloc_rt_sched_group+11d           |      7200/96    |      5400/72    |       75 |         0 | 25,000%
 copy_semundo+60                    |      2400/32    |      1800/24    |       75 |         7 | 25,000%
 ext4_readdir+825                   |      3264/64    |      2448/48    |       51 |         0 | 25,000%
 alloc_worker+1d                    |      8640/192   |      6480/144   |       45 |         0 | 25,000%
 alloc_workqueue_attrs+27           |      1440/32    |      1080/24    |       45 |         0 | 25,000%
 ext4_fill_super+57                 |     30720/2048  |     23040/1536  |       15 |         0 | 25,000%
 apply_wqattrs_prepare+32           |       960/64    |       720/48    |       15 |         0 | 25,000%
 inotify_handle_event+68            |       960/64    |       720/48    |       15 |         1 | 25,000%
 blk_alloc_queue_stats+1b           |       480/32    |       360/24    |       15 |         0 | 25,000%
 proc_self_get_link+57              |       160/16    |       120/12    |       10 |         0 | 25,000%
 disk_seqf_start+25                 |       256/32    |       192/24    |        8 |         0 | 25,000%
 memcg_write_event_control+8a       |       960/192   |       720/144   |        5 |         0 | 25,000%
 eventfd_file_create.part.3+28      |       320/64    |       240/48    |        5 |         0 | 25,000%
 do_seccomp+249                     |       160/32    |       120/24    |        5 |         0 | 25,000%
 mem_cgroup_oom_register_event+29   |       160/32    |       120/24    |        5 |         0 | 25,000%
 bucket_table_alloc+32              |       512/512   |       384/384   |        1 |         0 | 25,000%
 __kernfs_new_node+25               |     42424/33    |     32046/24    |     1284 |         2 | 24,463%
 single_open_size+2f                |     45056/4096  |     35024/3184  |       11 |         0 | 22,266%
 alloc_fdtable+ae                   |       544/90    |       424/70    |        6 |         0 | 22,059%
 __register_sysctl_paths+10f        |      2304/256   |      1800/200   |        9 |         0 | 21,875%
 pskb_expand_head+71                |     10240/2048  |      8000/1600  |        5 |         0 | 21,875%
 cpuacct_css_alloc+28               |      1280/256   |      1000/200   |        5 |         0 | 21,875%
 shmem_symlink+a5                   |      1440/13    |      1135/10    |      105 |         1 | 21,181%
 kernfs_fop_open+d5                 |    135168/192   |    107008/152   |      704 |         0 | 20,833%
 mb_cache_create+2c                 |      2880/192   |      2280/152   |       15 |         0 | 20,833%
 crypto_create_tfm+32               |      1440/96    |      1140/76    |       15 |         0 | 20,833%
 bpf_prog_alloc+9d                  |       960/192   |       760/152   |        5 |         0 | 20,833%
 pidlist_array_load+172             |       768/192   |       608/152   |        4 |         0 | 20,833%
 cgroup_mkdir+ca                    |     46080/1024  |     36540/812   |       45 |         2 | 20,703%
 __proc_create+a1                   |     17280/192   |     13740/152   |       90 |         0 | 20,486%
 __nf_conntrack_alloc+4e            |     20800/320   |     16640/256   |       65 |         2 | 20,000%
 devcgroup_css_alloc+1b             |      1280/256   |      1040/208   |        5 |         0 | 18,750%
 ext4_htree_store_dirent+35         |     27584/77    |     22770/64    |      354 |         0 | 17,452%
 copy_ipcs+63                       |      5120/1024  |      4240/848   |        5 |         4 | 17,188%
 __list_lru_init+225                |     10560/96    |      8800/80    |      110 |        16 | 16,667%
 device_private_init+1f             |      5760/192   |      4800/160   |       30 |         0 | 16,667%
 alloc_rt_sched_group+ef            |    153600/2048  |    129600/1728  |       75 |         0 | 15,625%
 ext4_fill_super+2907               |      1920/128   |      1620/108   |       15 |         0 | 15,625%
 __d_alloc+169                      |    107648/115   |     91360/97    |      934 |         0 | 15,131%
 copy_utsname+85                    |      2560/512   |      2200/440   |        5 |         4 | 14,062%
 kobject_set_name_vargs+1e          |     11904/66    |     10261/57    |      179 |        33 | 13,802%
 kasprintf+3a                       |     11744/91    |     10196/79    |      129 |        33 | 13,181%
 prepare_creds+21                   |    191808/192   |    167832/168   |      999 |        31 | 12,500%
 __seq_open_private+1c              |     16896/64    |     14784/56    |      264 |         0 | 12,500%
 start_this_handle+2da              |     29440/256   |     25760/224   |      115 |        90 | 12,500%
 load_elf_binary+1e8                |      3520/32    |      3080/28    |      110 |         0 | 12,500%
 alloc_fair_sched_group+11d         |     38400/512   |     33600/448   |       75 |         0 | 12,500%

__kthread_create_on_node+5e        |      3840/64    |      3360/56    |       60 |         0 | 12,500%
 wb_congested_get_create+86         |      2560/64    |      2240/56    |       40 |         0 | 12,500%
 bioset_create+2e                   |      3840/128   |      3360/112   |       30 |         0 | 12,500%
 kobj_map+83                        |       960/64    |       840/56    |       15 |         0 | 12,500%
 ext4_mb_init+54                    |       960/64    |       840/56    |       15 |         0 | 12,500%
 ext4_mb_init+2c                    |       480/32    |       420/28    |       15 |         0 | 12,500%
 alloc_fdtable+4b                   |       384/64    |       336/56    |        6 |         0 | 12,500%
 unix_bind+1a2                      |       640/128   |       560/112   |        5 |         0 | 12,500%
 kobject_get_path+56                |     30016/100   |     26522/88    |      299 |         0 | 11,640%
 __register_sysctl_table+51         |     20448/151   |     18288/135   |      135 |         0 | 10,563%
 create_cache+3e                    |     45696/384   |     40936/344   |      119 |        33 | 10,417%
 kvmalloc_node+3e                   |   2113536/25161 |   1897896/22594 |       84 |         0 | 10,203%
 dev_create+ab                      |      1440/96    |      1300/86    |       15 |         0 |  9,722%
 __anon_vma_prepare+d2              |    290576/88    |    264160/80    |     3302 |        81 |  9,091%
 anon_vma_fork+5e                   |    166672/88    |    151520/80    |     1894 |       187 |  9,091%
 kthread+3f                         |      5760/96    |      5280/88    |       60 |         0 |  8,333%
 thin_ctr+6f                        |      2880/192   |      2640/176   |       15 |         0 |  8,333%
 sock_alloc_inode+18                |    492096/704   |    452952/648   |      699 |        11 |  7,955%
 jbd2_journal_add_journal_head+67   |     48480/120   |     45248/112   |      404 |         1 |  6,667%
 do_execveat_common.isra.31+c0      |     37120/256   |     34800/240   |      145 |         6 |  6,250%
 kernfs_iattrs.isra.4+59            |     10112/128   |      9480/120   |       79 |         0 |  6,250%
 shmem_fill_super+25                |      3200/128   |      3000/120   |       25 |         0 |  6,250%
 bdi_alloc_node+2a                  |     15360/1024  |     14400/960   |       15 |         0 |  6,250%
 alloc_mnt_ns+54                    |      1152/128   |      1080/120   |        9 |         4 |  6,250%
 alloc_fair_sched_group+29          |       640/128   |       600/120   |        5 |         0 |  6,250%
 alloc_fair_sched_group+4e          |       640/128   |       600/120   |        5 |         0 |  6,250%
 alloc_rt_sched_group+29            |       640/128   |       600/120   |        5 |         0 |  6,250%
 alloc_rt_sched_group+4d            |       640/128   |       600/120   |        5 |         0 |  6,250%
 __register_sysctl_table+434        |     43776/270   |     41157/254   |      162 |         0 |  5,983%
 __kernfs_new_node+42               |    839528/136   |    790144/128   |     6173 |      1025 |  5,882%
 mqueue_alloc_inode+16              |      4800/960   |      4520/904   |        5 |         4 |  5,833%
 bpf_prepare_filter+24b             |     40960/8192  |     38920/7784  |        5 |         0 |  4,980%
 bpf_convert_filter+57              |     20480/4096  |     19460/3892  |        5 |         0 |  4,980%
 bpf_prepare_filter+111             |     10240/2048  |      9730/1946  |        5 |         0 |  4,980%
 ep_alloc+3d                        |     24576/192   |     23552/184   |      128 |        11 |  4,167%
 inet_twsk_alloc+3a                 |      1736/248   |      1680/240   |        7 |         0 |  3,226%
 mm_alloc+16                        |    296960/2048  |    290000/2000  |      145 |        10 |  2,344%
 copy_process.part.40+9e6           |    202752/2048  |    198000/2000  |       99 |        11 |  2,344%
 mempool_create_node+f3             |    235920/425   |    230520/415   |      555 |         0 |  2,289%
 dax_alloc_inode+16                 |     11520/768   |     11280/752   |       15 |         0 |  2,083%
 bdev_alloc_inode+16                |     12480/832   |     12240/816   |       15 |         0 |  1,923%
 ext4_find_extent+290               |    423552/99    |    415440/97    |     4243 |         0 |  1,915%
 radix_tree_node_alloc.constprop.19+78 |   5331336/584   |   5258304/576   |     9129 |         8 |  1,370%
 alloc_inode+66                     |    528352/608   |    521400/600   |      869 |        20 |  1,316%
 proc_alloc_inode+16                |    928200/680   |    917280/672   |     1365 |        45 |  1,176%
 copy_process.part.40+95d           |    483648/2112  |    478152/2088  |      229 |         8 |  1,136%
 shmem_alloc_inode+16               |    326096/712   |    322432/704   |      458 |         6 |  1,124%
 copy_process.part.40+10fe          |    234496/1024  |    232664/1016  |      229 |        12 |  0,781%
 ext4_alloc_inode+17                |    647360/1088  |    642600/1080  |      595 |         1 |  0,735%
 __vmalloc_node_range+d3            |     13192/30    |     13112/30    |      426 |        36 |  0,606%
 sk_prot_alloc+2f                   |    544768/1127  |    542080/1122  |      483 |         6 |  0,493%
...

SUMMARY (SLAB allocator)
========================
Total bytes requested: 818.739.691
Total bytes allocated: 821.951.696
Total bytes freed:     763.705.848
Net total bytes allocated: 58.245.848
Total bytes wasted on internal fragmentation: 3.212.005
Internal fragmentation: 0,390778%
Cross CPU allocations: 28.844/10.157.339
```

Comment: try `top -o %MEM`

Comment: This is not the problem: I can sort the top-output with SHIFT-M, however most memory- comsuming process is 'dmeventd' with 17MB RES-memory. The output above was also ordered after memory.

Comment: Ok, I see... Then what does `cat /proc/meminfo` say?

Comment: I added it to my inital question.

Comment: Ok, so slab is the problem (`SUnreclaim:      5483636 kB`). We need `/proc/slabinfo` now ;) Ok, this might be big, maybe you can identify yourself which kernel driver allocates so much memory. I just saw that there is also a tool called `slabtop`, which might come in handy here

Comment: top of slabtop added above :-)

Comment: Ok, so `kmalloc-1024` uses up all the memory. Unfortunately this is a bit unspecific....  If you do not have a suspicion at all what in your kernel might kmalloc the memory, you will have to reboot, gather performance data with `perf kmem record --caller`, wait until some significant amount of memory is used up again and then evaluate the data with `perf kmem stat --caller`.

Comment: I do call: 'perf kmem record --caller' after reboot as root, wait a day and call then 'perf kmem stat --caller'. Right?

Comment: It is a official linux image from Amazon 'Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03'. I'm a bit surprised to see such a problem. I think amazon is a little bit known...

Comment: Yes,I suggest you start it inside a `screen` (since it remains in the foreground). Perhaps amazon knows the problem, have you asked the support?

Comment: I added my problem to https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ but your help was faster. I'm sure I come back.

Comment: Do you use btrfs? Some people seem to have exactly the same problem with it, which vanished, after switching to ext4

Comment: One more thing: perf data might grow rapidly (file perf.data), you have to keep an eye on the free disk space

Comment: I have ext4. I will check pref.data. Thank you very much.

Comment: I added the result of 'perf kmem stat --caller'  above.